# footer at bottom with ajax loaded content

Tags: css, position, footer

I have this html structure with the section being basically my main content:

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>
  <nav id="primary">
  <nav id="secondary">
  <section id="maincontainer">
    <div id="main">...</div>
    <footer>
     <div class="footer-inner">...</div>
    </footer>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Within the div with id 'main' there is content being dynamically loaded via ajax, so the height can vary. 
I need the footer to always be at the bottom, even for sub pages with barely any content not filling the page height.
Currently I have position absolute for the footer, which does not work for the dynamic content pages, the footer is stuck in the middle of the content (original window height position).

Is there a way to do this css only?
Thank you!

Comment: footer will have fix content?

Comment: yes, just some links.

Comment: check my answwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
<footer style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%;"> </footer>
```

You can also read about `flex` it is supported by all modern browsers

**Update:**
I read about flex and tried it. It worked for me. Hope it does the same for you. Here is how I implemented.Here main is not the ID it is the `<main>` div

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main {
    display: block;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Here you can read more about flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Do keep in mind it is not supported by older versions of IE.

Comment: I dont want the footer to be visible at all times. It really should be all at the bottom in the end, below all the content. fixed didnt help me there.

Answer (score -1):

> **Method 1:** Using calc() property by wrapping the header and content in one div.

```css
body,html{ margin:0px; padding:0px;height:100%}
.wrapper{height:calc(100% - 50px);}

footer{ height:50px; background:red;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="primary"></nav>
  <nav id="secondary"></nav>
  <section id="maincontainer">
    <div id="main">...</div>
  </section> 
 </div> 
    <footer>
     <div class="footer-inner">Footer</div>
    </footer>
```

> **Method 2:** By using -ve height of footer with the wrapper element.

```css
body,html{ margin:0px; padding:0px;height:100%}



.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -50px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 50px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <nav id="primary"></nav>
  <nav id="secondary"></nav>
  <section id="maincontainer">
    <div id="main">...</div>
  </section> 
 </div> 
    <footer class="site-footer">
     <div class="footer-inner">Footer</div>
    </footer>
```

**EDIT**

> **Method 3:** using same structure and calc().

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%
}

#primary {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}

#secondary {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

#maincontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 130px);
}

#main {
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="primary">Nav 1</nav>
  <nav id="secondary">Nav 2</nav>
  <section id="maincontainer">
    <div id="main">...</div>
    <footer>
     <div class="footer-inner">...</div>
    </footer>
  </section>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the html structure, my footer needs to be inside the section.

Comment: Method 3 is really close! But because of the dynamic content the calc() function does not know about the height in the end and calculates wrongly.

Comment: the height of content  =  100% - ( height of navs + height of footer) = 100% - 130px  .. You can share more code so I can see the actual problem

Answer (score -1):

Using `bottom:0;` `position:fixed` for footer style You can easily achieve what you want.

```css
body,html{ margin:0px; padding:0px;height:100%}



.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -50px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
}
.site-footer {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <nav id="primary"></nav>
  <nav id="secondary"></nav>
  <section id="maincontainer">
    <div id="main">...</div>

    <footer class="site-footer">
     <div class="footer-inner">Footer</div>
    </footer>
  </section> 
 </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I dont want the footer to be visible at all times. It really should be all at the bottom in the end, below all the content. fixed didnt help me there.